# Customize Convert to Opportunity Dialog in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Can we customize the Convert to Opportunity dialog?

Let say i need to add one of my CRM field to the dialog and make that field required so that user should provide a value for it and then create an opportunity.

Reason for asking this question is:
I have a field called Opportunity Type and based on that field i have different Opportunity forms defined.So, if i can get the field into the Dialog it will be much helpful for me to load the respective form using my javascript.

Please let me know whether this can be achievable or Not...?

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty doable. Actually you can implement your own dialog, and use it instead of standard one. To get all necessary fields you can use CRM SDK, and fetch all info via Javascript calls from you page.

Answer (score 1):

Like Sergey said it's possible if you implement your own dialog. You just need add a ribbon button to call a new dialog, you can hide the default button. See [here](http://garethtuckercrm.com/2012/04/03/building-custom-screens-using-dialogs-and-ribbon-buttons-in-crm-2011/) a example.